# Convert from factor to numeric a column in data.frames within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, type-conversion, numeric

Here an example of my two lists and relative code:

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10))
df2 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,11))

lst = list(df1, df2)

lst_table = lapply(lst, function(x) data.frame(table(x$a))) 

> class(lst_table[[1]]$Var1)
[1] "factor"
> class(lst_table[[2]]$Var1)
[1] "factor"
```

Because of my code purpose I need the column `Var1` within each data.frame in the list to be a numeric vector.

Starting from [How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) I applied the following code to the single data.frames and it works:

```
> df1$a = as.numeric(levels(df1$a))[df1$a]
> df2$a = as.numeric(levels(df2$a))[df2$a]

> class(df1$a)
[1] "numeric"
> class(df2$a)
[1] "numeric"
```

**But how can I apply the above to a list?**

I tried:

```
lst_table = lapply(lst_table, function(y) {y$Var1 = as.numeric(levels(y$Var1))[y$Var1]})
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: will you always have the same amount of numbers in each array or could they both be 5 then later both be 10?

Comment: my real data.frames within my real list differ in length and type of observations. thanks

Comment: ok, will they be the same length as each other or can the length of each be different at the same time?

Comment: no, their length can be different at the same time, e.g. df1 = 22380 rows and df2 = 11654 rows, and the list contains df1 and df2.

Comment: my idea wouldnt work then

Comment: ok, no problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your function in your second `lapply` is only returning the vector of the numeric factor levels, not your entire `data.frame`. I believe the following should work:

```
foo <- function(y) {
  y$Var1 <- as.numeric(levels(y$Var1))[y$Var1]
  return(y)
}

lst_table <- lapply(lst_table, foo)
```